# building dependencies for Apache Spark on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-spark

I would like to use eclipse for an Apache Spark project, but building dependencies appears not to work. I keep getting

"Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor (execution: default-descriptor, phase: generate-resources)"

Following the directions on the Apache spark site, https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html
I am running CDH5 cluster. using maven. Here is my generated pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-    4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
<version>1.1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>spark-core_2.10</name>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

  <dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```
   <repositories>
 <repository>
     <id>Cloudera repository</id>
      <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
   </repository>
   </repositories>



  <dependencyManagement>
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am a new Maven/POM user. How do i solve this issue and stop getting errors in my java code?

Comment: I think this error is with maven can you check you maven proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to be related to m2e plugin. Take a look [https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html.](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html)
However the pom you expose is strange, the groupId and artifactId should be related to the path and name of your project, and not to the dependency that you try to use (in this case, spark-core_2.10).